# Function defined with __declspec(dllexport) in .h file but not in .c file discards __declspec(dllexport)

Tags: mingw

I noticed several projects fail to build into a shared library on Windows with MinGW-w64 because they define functions with `__declspec(dllexport)` in the header file, but the implementation later on doesn't repeat `__declspec(dllexport)`, causing MinGW GCC to discard the first `__declspec(dllexport)`.

The message I get then is

```
'functionname' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Werror=attributes]
```

How can I tell MinGW GCC to keep `__declspec(dllexport)` when it is missing the second time?

Comment: The `__declspec(dllexport)` doesn't have to be repeated in the implementation, provided the implementation includes the header file where these functions were defined.

Comment: @ssbssa I did a simple test case and that proved you are right. However, I have multiple projects resulting in `redeclared without dllimport attribute:
previous dllimport ignored`, maybe this is cause by a specific compiler flag...

Comment: Well, this is about `dllimport`, not dllexport. I'm guessing you have some define that chooses which one of them should be used, and it looks like this doesn't work, or that define is not set correctly.

Comment: You are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `redeclared without dllimport attribute` actually indicates the header file defined the functions with `__declspec(dllimport)` instead of `__declspec(dllexport)`.

The solution was to have the right define in place (with a `-D` compiler flag) so the functions are defined with `__declspec(dllimport)`.

One specific example of this was djvulibre-3.5.27 where I had to build with `make -Clibdjvu CFLAGS="-DDJVUAPI_EXPORT -DDDJVUAPI_EXPORT -DMINILISPAPI_EXPORT" CXXFLAGS="-DDJVUAPI_EXPORT -DDDJVUAPI_EXPORT -DMINILISPAPI_EXPORT"` before running `make` for the rest of the package.